# recompiling opencv efficiently after changing a single .cpp file

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, compilation

I have been attempting to modify opencv a bit and can't figure out how to compile on ubuntu 14.04 efficiently.  To get my new code to compile and use the cv2.so file from python (import cv2) I generally have to nuke the build directory , do a cmake , make, make install, and copy the cv2.so by hand to a /usr/lib directory.  Is there some way to avoid recompiling the whole shebang (abt 20min) every time I tweak something small in the single .cpp file I am actually changing?

Comment: You can change the makefiles to compile `.c` files into object files first and then all the object files into `.so` ones if it wasn't done already.

Comment: the system uses cmake , with a CMakelists.txt that seems to be autogenerated .   I've never edited such, if anyone has specific experience pls clue me in.